# MsgBox and SQL 'Insert Into' query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

In a MS-Access DB I have the below SQL query fired from a VBA module that appends a record given the conditions stated in the WHERE clause. My question is, can I insert a MsgBox that informs the user if the record already exists or weather is a new record? Currently the query will append a record if the value for the field called 'Counterparty ID' is already in the destination table, and won't if not. While the mechanics are correct, I would like to notify the user whether he/she has tried to insert a duplicate record. Is this somehow possible? I assume it would have to happen within the query itself.

```
"INSERT INTO Netting_Determinations_List ([Counterparty ID], [Counterparty Name], [Counterparty Type], [Counterparty Subtype],[DTCC_AVOX_Registered_LEI_CICI], " & _
        "[Data Point 1],[Data Point 2],[Data Point 3],[Data Point 4],[Data Point 5], [Matrix Legal Form], [Matrix Governing/Authorizing Power], " & _
        "[OnBoardings Color Determination], [Matrix Clarification],  [Audit_Append_User], [Audit_Append_Date], [Audit_Append_Time]) " & _
        "SELECT Repository_Redux.[Counterparty ID], Repository_Redux.[Counterparty Name], Repository_Redux.[Counterparty Type], Repository_Redux.[Counterparty Subtype], Repository_Redux.[DTCC_AVOX_Registered_LEI_CICI], " & _
        "[Forms]![Frm_Master_Form]![Txt_Input_1] AS [Data Point 1], [Forms]![Frm_Master_Form]![Txt_Input_2] AS [Data Point 2], " & _
        "[Forms]![Frm_Master_Form]![Txt_Input_3] AS [Data Point 3], [Forms]![Frm_Master_Form]![Txt_Input_4] AS [Data Point 4], " & _
        "[Forms]![Frm_Master_Form]![Txt_Input_5] AS [Data Point 5], [Forms]![Frm_Master_Form]![Cbo_LegalForm] AS [Matrix Legal Form], " & _
        "[Forms]![Frm_Master_Form]![Cbo_Status] AS [Matrix Governing/Authorizing Power], [Forms]![Frm_Master_Form]![Txt_Color] AS [OnBoardings Color Determination], " & _
        "[Forms]![Frm_Master_Form]![Txt_Matrix_Clarification] AS [Matrix Clarification], '" & strUsername & "' AS [Audit_Append_User], " & _
        "'" & StrDate & "' AS [Audit_Append_Date], '" & StrTime & "' AS [Audit_Append_Time] FROM Repository_Redux " & _
        "WHERE Repository_Redux.[Counterparty ID] IN (" & strCriteria & ") AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Counterparty ID] FROM Netting_Determinations_List WHERE [Counterparty ID] = (" & strCriteria & "))"
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Write an aggregate query that counts the number of records matching your new record. If that count is > 0 then you inform the user. Use Dlookup to do the work for you. You don't need a Recordset object or anything that complicated.

Comment: I think you are on the right track here. Though untrained I think I can figure it out. If you're into SO points might wanna put your comment in the answers so I can upvote it

Comment: Use DCount followed by a message. You could even use the result returned by the DCount as a condition to run or not run your query.

Comment: Yes I think so. If I was to do that I could probably get rid of the second where condition in the query I posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would go about it:

```
If Nz(DLookup("Counterparty ID","Netting_Determinations_List","[Counterparty ID]=" & strCriteria),0)=0 then
--Record does not exists, insert
else
--record exists notify user
end if
```

Don't bother trying to find out if a record was inserted. Much easier to check for the record first and take action accordingly.

Comment: yes this is it. I removed the records from the source in this specific case but what you outline would be the correct way to check if the record is there and provide a message box before the user takes action.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access is notoriously simplistic in how it handles records.  For example, you can call an insert from VBA (Database.Execute "insert...") and it might silently fail to insert; you have to go verify yourself that what you wanted written was actually inserted.  (The DoSQL action will pop up dialogs, however.)

Since you are using VBA, I'd recommend that you first do the test in SQL yourself.  Either create a query object or execute the query text that selects whether the record exists (Recordset.RecordCount > 0), and then pop up a dialog informing the user about it.  You can't write this into the query text.

Note that you might have to do a .MoveLast and .MoveFirst to get the actual record count, depending on the recordset type.

Comment: I should share that my query is fired in VBA but uses a DoCmd.OpenQuery that calls a SQL query so I do get the dialog as you correctly indicate. However if I count records it shouldn't work because the record will be there, whether the user attempted a duplicate or not... I think I should run a SELECT IN query before the above SQL is called to verify if the record is there already and if there exit the sub.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean-- run the select test query before you run the insert query.  Is that what you're saying?  You count the records from the select test query so see if it already exists; if there are none, you can safely insert without worry.  If there are some, then alert the user and don't do the insert.

Comment: Yes correct. I ended up removing the record from the listbox I was using as recordsource thereby preventing duplicates but your suggestion was correct.